# Why the checkboxes are not sent though request?

Tags: bootstrap-4, request

I am doing a form with checkboxes, but I can't make it send to the view. The request only send the csrf token. What I am doing wrong?

```
<form action="select" method="POST">

<div class="form-check">
    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="{{ subject.id }}" id="flexCheckDefault{{ subject.grouper }}{{ subject.id }}" >
    <label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault-{{ subject.name }}">
        {{ subject.name }}
    </label>
</div>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary  pull-left"><i class="fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>
```

Request:

```
csrfmiddlewaretoken=VQRxpROz9G9b1ObLSqBX7AP6JaIneD2sW1lxRFNjypEuuKCPOM2GEtoMD383u53S
```

---

Edit:
I find out I wasn't sending the variable name in the checkbox, so the data was sent, but I could not see in the request.

Comment: I don't understand what the question has to do with either Python or Django. What ended up in the **actual HTML in your browser**? **How are you verifying** the contents of the request?

Answer (score 0):

The action attribute of a form determines where the post request is directed and generally contains a URL, either absolute (action="https://www.example.com") or relative (action="/UserProfile"). Relative URLs are more common for POST requests.

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp

I second the comment about how this got labeled as Python or Django, though.